# Deviding strings and integers of user input

Tags: java, string, input, integer

I'm new to coding. I want to try out a few things using java with eclipse. In this programm the user should be able to use a few commands. For example a command called "add".
So when the user is typing "add 15 -200" the programm should call the add method and give it those to parameters. Sadly I have no idea how to properly read the integers and give them the "add" method. I just don't see how to devide the "add" string from the integers. Please help! Thanks in advance! 
Take care

Comment: Please show some code to us.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public final class Test {

```
private static boolean quit = false;
private static final String PROMPT = "prompt> ";

int add( int i, int j) {
int result = i + j;
System.out.println(result);
return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!quit) {
        System.out.print(PROMPT);
        String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if(input.trim().equals("help") || input.trim().equals("h")) {
            System.out.println("Try one of the following commands: ");
            System.out.println("add n1 n2 : adds n1 to n2");
            System.out.println("quit : quits the programm");
        } else if(input.trim().equals("quit") || input.trim().equals("q")) {
            quit = true;
        } else if(input.equals("add ")) {;
        }
    }
}
```

}

that's my code so far. As you can see the last else if statement is empty because I have no idea how to sepperate strings with integers.